# Is there a better name for "Last In, Random Out?"

Tags: random, collections, stack, queue

So we've all heard of LIFO, FIFO, FILO, and LILO. (Last in, first out, etc.) What about LIRO? Last in, random out. Is that a common collection management pattern?

This occurs more commonly in nature, right? For example: water-homeostasis. If you drink too much water, the body's kidneys finds a way to get rid of the excess. Except, it's not the last water molecule that gets pushed out. Or the first. Whatever water molecule happens to be passing through the kidneys at the time is outputted.

I've been thinking about how to articulate this better in context of computing. Perhaps the analogy is irrelevant. In the case of water-homeostasis, all molecules are exactly the same (i.e., the values are the same even of the referenced object is not).

**Update:**

Upon further discussion, a colleague recommended that "Any In, Random Out" would be more pertinent.

In some of the responses, it was suggested that the input has no effect on the output. I don't think this is entirely true. Consider the following collection:

```
[3, 7, 3, 7, 7]
```

Even if the ordinality is random, the output is not. For example, the collection could not yield 5, 8, or 3,000,000. The input not only affects the range of eligible output values, it could (as in my analogy) trigger the output.

Comment: If it’s random out, what is the use of a “last in” designator?

Comment: "Last In, Random Out" makes literally no sense.

Comment: I somewhat agree that it makes no sense. Except, software is meant to be an articulation of "real life" business rules. Following the metaphor, the glass of water you drink is the last in. This triggers the hormonal messaging (in the event that your body is holding too much water) sent to the kidneys.  The water expelled by the kidneys is "random" out (determined by chance). This is why I'm asking the question. I'm looking for a better way to communicate this "business rule" in terms of software.

Comment: That "business" rule (exactly the same as in your analogy) is simply called "random". The input has nothing to do with it.

Comment: "Any In, Random Out" is exactly the same as "random out". How that set was defined (by non-random inputs, or by a constant, or any other method), has _no bearing on the output selection method_ so don't mention it.

Comment: Since posting this question, I've stumble upon a similar concept used by Amazon's Simple Queue Service (SQS). As an alternative to their FIFO option, they offer [SQS Standard Queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html) in favor of decoupling and multitasking.

AWS' solution is to call this pattern "standard," but since this pattern occurs more often in nature, it would be nice to have a more descriptive name.

Answer (score -1):

LIFO, FIFO, FILO, and LILO are so named to describe the relationship between input and output.

In your case, there is no relationship between input and output, so copying that naming schema doesn't make sense.

Your output logic is simply called:  Random.

Comment: I think this is more than simply "random," as the input not only has an effect on triggering the output, it limits the available range. I've updated my post for clarity. Thank you!

Comment: Your update changes nothing. You're still randomly outputing members of the set. This is still called "random" "Pick a number between one and ten" is called "random", even though the result cannot exceed 10.